# Alternative to Sandboxie

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualization, sandbox, sandboxie

I've been using Sandboxie for some time now in order to run multiple instances of one program. The program has been updated and no longer runs in Sandboxie. I am looking for an alternative sandboxing program that is similar to Sandboxie.

It has to have the ability to create multiple independent sandboxes that can be run at the same time (like in the paid version of sandboxie).

I've tried some programs but they all either have only one sandbox or work in a different way.
I have tried: BitBox, BufferZone, GesWall, Hopedot VOS, WinJail. The closest match I've found is the Comodo Sandbox but again, it only has one sandbox without the ability to create more.

Are there any other programs that have these features? VM is not an option.

Comment: I think this question is also relevant on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Try posting it there as well

Comment: This appears to be asking for a software recomendation which is not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: I posted on software recommendations as well.

Comment: I would normally indicated we frown upon cross site posting but we can't migrate to beta stackexchange websites but this is still not on topic here

Comment: the link to your post in "software recommendations" https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/alternative-to-sandboxie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying more programs, Avast sandbox is the only acceptable alternative. It does not have multiple sandboxes but it does have an option to run each process independently of other processes in the sandbox and on the system, which can also do.

Out of all the programs that I've tried, Avast is the best alternative to Sandboxie. The sandbox module can be installed separately without any antivirus parts so that's a plus as well.